# Why do we need to initialize late a class on run time and not directly on compile time in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-null-safety

I'm wondering, if we create an instance of a class, we create the instance first and mark it as late before assigning a value on the initState? Why dont we just assign a value to it at compile time directly?

```dart
//what is the difference of this
SampleClass _sample = SampleClass();

//with this?
late SampleClass _sample;

void initState(){
  super.initState():
  _sample = SampleClass();
}
```

Comment: If you *can* avoid using `late`, like in this case, you should.  Typically you'd use `late` only when you have to.  For example, case where initialization depends on other runtime values.  Even in those cases, I probably would lean toward using nullable variables instead of `late` ones.

Answer (score 1):

When `SampleClass` depends on [context](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/BuildContext-class.html), the initialization must happen in `initState` which is when the widget is inserted into the tree, otherwise no need to delay the initialization.

Comment: what do you mean by `context`?...I see a lot of tutorial if they instantiate a class, they do:
void(){
late MockService mock;

setUp((){
mock = MockService():
}
}

what is the context here for example?

Comment: Take a look at https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/BuildContext-class.html.